# Application Gateway WAF end to end SSL

Tags: apache, azure, azure-application-gateway

I have recently enabled WAF and moved some of our web applications behind it. We have not faced any issues with HTTP sites but we are facing issues with end-to-end SSL. We initially faced an issue with the certificate on the backend server which has since been sorted out by MS Support. Our backend web server is running Apache with multiple HTTPS sites on the same server and the issue we face is regardless of the HTTPS site we try to access, only the url in first lines of Apache config is returned. Completely clueless on how to sort this out.

**Question:** Has anyone been able to implement end-to-end SSL with multiple HTTPS sites on the same Apache server?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a combination of basic rule and path based rule, and if the basic rule is listed above the path based rule, then basic rule is preferred. Can you delete the basic rule (if any) which is pointing to the HTTP Settings and backend pool that returns the first lines of Apache config?